# How can I auto-increment available options for an integer field?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a set of available options for an integer field:

```
2011|2011
2012|2012
2013|2013
...etc
```

The thing is I want years all the way to 2050. Is there a way to set a step increment in this field? I could create the list in a text editor and paste it, but I'd love to find a more elegant solution using code or some way of incrementing the options.

Answer (score 1):

> I could create the list in a text editor and paste it

You can use Microsoft Excel. on A(1) put 2015 on A(2) put 2016.

Highlight both cells, click on the bottom right corner (you will get a + cursor) and drag down.